# not able to crop image

Tags: jquery, html, image, crop

I have created an application used **[cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)** for cropping an images, the application is working and the image is comming but I am not able to crop the image. My code is as given below

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VDgWLfJ6jrYP63GMwkmm?p=preview)**

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/img/picture.jpg" />
</div>
```

**script**

```
$('.container > img').cropper({ 
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop: function(data) {
    // Output the result data for cropping image.
  }
});
```

Comment: don't you nee dot set an `aspectRatio`?

Comment: is it mandatory, how we can set that

Comment: as per the examples giving on the github repo you've linked to

Comment: @atmd okay I have updated , added aspect ratio, still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire your cropper code in a doc ready block, like this:

```
$(function (){
    $('.container > img').cropper({ 
       aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
       crop: function(data) {
       // Output the result data for cropping image.
       }
    });
});
```

You where running the crop code before the image had been rendered in the dom